# Is there a software that can do derivatives with respect to user defined vibrational modes?

Tags: software, electronic-structure, software-recommendations, mathematical-modeling, vibrations

I'm doing some property calculations that depend on a sum of derivatives of some quantity with respect to normal vibrational modes. I was hoping to find some physical intuition relating the type of mode to its property contribution, but there isn't an obvious connection in the normal mode basis.

I decided to try converting to a different mode basis to see if there is a more obvious connection. I'm able to convert the modes using a unitary transformation, but I can't seem to convert derivatives to the new basis properly (the unitary transformed derivatives don't match numerical derivatives along the transformed modes).

I asked separately [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/928/discrepancy-between-numerical-and-transformed-derivatives) about any errors with my transformation method. For this question, I'm more curious if this already solved in an existing program?

**Is there an electronic structure program that can perform derivatives with respect to vibrational modes and allows the user to define the modes?**

Comment: What kind of custom basis are you interested in? Also, I presume you are wanting the second derivatives, the first derivative should be zero at stationary points.  I could provide an answer for getting second derivatives of internal coordinates, which are intuitive

Comment: Oh wait, you want derivative of vibrational modes, so that's like the third derivative of energy

Comment: @CodyAldaz realized I had a pretty significant mistype. I'm doing property derivatives, say how the polarizablity changes along each vibrational mode. In my particular case, I'm looking at localized modes rather than the normal modes that are typically calculated.

Comment: Presumably, the unitary transformation should work. Maybe, its failing because the property you are trying to transform is written in terms of Cartesians (i.e. 3Nx3N rather than 3N-6 dimensional) therefore, this causes it to fail.

Comment: +1. How bad is the disagreement with the numerical derivatives and how confident are you that the latter are accurate?

Comment: @NikeDattani I'm able to get accurate numerical derivatives for the normal modes. I suspect there is some issue with mass-weighting of coordinates,  as I need to include the square-root of the reduced mass of the mode as a factor in numerical derivative to get a matching result for the normal modes. I suspect that something screws up the mass weighting during the transformation. I may post a separate question about addressing the underlying problem, rather than looking for other software that can do the derivatives.

Comment: Have you remembered to apply the inverse-transformation to the derivatives? Derivatives transform in the opposite way to the coordinates.

Comment: As this is now one of the oldest unanswered questions, I wonder if Phil's suggestion was helpful?

Comment: @NikeDattani I realized I tried to address your comment, but didn't reply here. I included a link in this post to my other one about the actual derivative computation. I have tried a couple different ways of applying the unitary matrix, but none have seemed to work. For now, I think I will close this question rather than add a "no, such a software doesn't exist yet" answer.

Comment: This can be done in siesta using a Lua interface with custom defined modes. However, we experienced the problem of not getting better modes anyway. The exact reason is not clear to me. Our idea was that the modes would be *better*. However, it seems that this isn't better than just doing xyz.

Comment: @nickpapior I would accept that as an answer. Its been awhile since I worked on this particular project, but I think an answer pointing out how this can be done could be useful to other users.

Comment: I'm aware of a vibrational perturbation theory code that can do this (provided the energies and/or hessians as inputs) but it isn't publicly available. So that's not very helpful, but it will be available eventually. I could point you to the group to contact for all answers about this type of question. Also, per your comment about mass-weighting, it sounds like you might be forgetting to properly incorporate the G-matrix into your transformations. Depending on the transformation you're doing, the elements of the G-matrix become more complicated than just the square root of the masses.

Comment: @jheindel Do you think you could ask someone from that group to come here and answer this question? 

Comment: Would one of the various quantum chemistry packages that offer "automatic derivatives", such as PySCFad, help with this? You would be able to do a derivative of basically anything with respect to anything, because you would be differentiating the whole computer program (or subroutine, or code block), based on the principle that all `DO` loops, `IF` statements, or whatever else in the code, boil down to additions and multiplications whose *analytic* derivatives can be put togetger using the chain rule. Even Fortran's `SIN()` and `COS()` functions boil down to hardware adders, multipliers, etc.